# New tuple from a mess tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I'm facing a trouble with creating a new tuple. I'm kinda new in python.

Suppose I have a list of tuple :

```
a = [1,2,6,4,5]
b = [3,7,3,4,6]
[((11, 5, 6), n), ((9, 6, 3), n), ((9, 2, 7), n), ((8, 4, 4), n), ((4, 1, 3), n)]
```

which belongs to `[(a+b,a,b),n=count(zip(a,b)),...........]`

My final goal is to make a tuple like this:
(removing a+b, and put 'n' value into the tuple)

```
[(5,6,n), (6,3,n), .... ] 
[(a,b,n),  .....]
```

is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: `is there a way to make this happen?` of course there is. What have you tried so far? Because this question is super broad atm.

Comment: `count` is not a defined name in Python, and your list-comp syntax is incorrect, you can not do variable assignment inside a list-comp (`n=`). So please modify your question to include your `count` function, and correct your syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use tuple unpacking:

```
[(a, b, n) for ((_, a, b), n) in T]
```

Where `T` is the input and the result is in the requested form.

Example:

```
>>> T = [((11, 5, 6), 1), ((9, 6, 3), 2), ((9, 2, 7), 3), ((8, 4, 4), 4), ((4, 1, 3), 5)]
>>> [(a, b, n) for ((_, a, b), n) in T]
[(5, 6, 1), (6, 3, 2), (2, 7, 3), (4, 4, 4), (1, 3, 5)]
```

I've replaced the `n`'s with numbers 1 to 5.

Comment: perfect! I never used it before but looks very handy. thanks @Dan !

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit confusing what you wrote.

Maybe you want this:

```
zip(a,b,[sum(x) for x in zip(a,b)])
```

What it does:

1. `zip()` [returs a list of tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip)

Note that tuples and list are two different data structures.
In your question, `a = []` and b = [] are lists of integers, not [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=tuples).

2. a syntax of `[ f(x) for x in g(y,z)]` is equivalent to pseudo-code:

   ```
   for each_item in iterable_like_a_list_is:
        apply f() to each_item
        return a list of f(x) items
   ```

It is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.0.html?highlight=list%20comprehension).

3. finally apply `zip(x, y, z)` to three lists. 
   In your case, a, b and the a+b obtained at step 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your question, but suppose we know the 'n' value for every tuple (i fixed my n's to 1)

The naive solution is (without tuple unpacking)

```
n = 1
x = [((11, 5, 6), n), ((9, 6, 3), n), ((9, 2, 7), n), ((8, 4, 4), n), ((4, 1, 3), n)]
y= [(tuple_[0][1],tuple_[0][2], tuple_[1]) for tuple_ in x]
print(y)
```

which prints

```
[(5, 6, 1), (6, 3, 1), (2, 7, 1), (4, 4, 1), (1, 3, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks @nikaidoh! it's working. n is the result of the occurrence of the tuple after I used Counter(tuple). And that list is the result after I sorted the dictionary in descending order.